If a file does not exist, create a new one. Does this work in Perl?
Will the following code create a new file if the original is missing?
#### If file does not exist, create a new file
if (!-e $fh) { 
    open (FILE, ">$fh");
    print FILE "\n";
    close (FILE);
}


Can you not test this code yourself and get the answer to that question?

Some feedback: 1) you should always check the return value of open to see if it failed, e.g. or die ..., 2) you should use a lexical file handle, and 3-argument open, with explicit open mode, to prevent code injection. E.g. open my $fh, ">", $file or die "Cannot open '$file': $!".

If you open for append, it will create it if it doesn't exist.
open( my $fh, ">>", $qfn )
   or die( "Can't open or create `$qfn`: $!\n" );

Note the use of 3-arg open. Avoid the 2-arg open.
Note the use of a lexical variable. Avoid the needless use of global variables.
Note that a variable named $fh usually stores a file handle, not a file name.

No need for the if( ! -e $fh).
of course the open() with ">$fh" will truncate the file, not append to it, so if you're looking for an append operation you need the following:
open(my $handle, ">>", "$fh");


No, append is >>. That mode +> means it is opened for both reading and writing. Which is useless, since the file is truncated.

Thank you TLP for refreshing my perl.  It's been a minute. :)

There are cases where the modification time (or other metadata) of the file matters. If you aren't going to add anything, sometimes you don't want to change the meta data.

Fair point as well @briandfoy.
